# Add JS file on a certain page on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, javascript

I've got a JS file that I want to add to Admin>Add Content>Certain Content type 
After looking at template.php and checking out the function theme_preprocess_node 
I tried to add the JS through drupal_add_js(...) but no go. 
Now, I know that there's a similar question however my case is about adding 
a JS file to a certain page and nothing else (better seperation of JS files).

Thanks. 
*(Drupal 6)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [drupal_add_js() in page template not working](http://drupal.org/node/482542).

The gist of it is that calling `drupal_add_js()` (or `drupal_add_css()`) during preprocess functions is basically to late, as the markup for the js/css inclusion has already been rendered into a variable. To work around this, you need to overwrite the variable again by calling `drupal_get_js()` after your addition:

```
function yourThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Is this a node addition page for the specific content type?
  // TODO: Adjust the content type to your needs
  // NOTE: Will only work for the node add form - if you want your js to be
  // included for edit forms as well, you need to enhance the check accordingly
  if ('node' == arg(0) && 'add' == arg(1) && 'yourContentType' == arg(2)) {
    // Add your js file as usual
    drupal_add_js('path/to/your/file.js', 'theme');
    // Ensure that the addition has any effect by repopulating the scripts variable
    $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

NOTE: Use `preprocess_page`, not `preprocess_node` for this, as javascript inclusion should happen in the page template. Also, Kevins hint on the need to rebuild the theme registry still applies (+1).

Comment: This is correct! I explain how to add in custom js at theme level here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051765/drupal-customizing-modules-question/3053291#3053291

Comment: alright however it seems like this JS file would be loaded on every page, whereas I want it to be loaded on a certain page (waste of load time otherwise)

Comment: @ASAF: You seem to have missed the 'TODO' comment in the example ;)

Comment: @ASAF: OK, I just added the page checking logic.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your module could you just do a:

```
function your_module_name_init() {
    if(arg(0) == "some_name") {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name') . '/your_js_file_name.js');
    }
}
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the drupal_add_js, did you clear the theme/site cache? That should work.